# Is my code overtaxing my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, data-structures, memory-management

In my application, I'm maintaining an `NSMutableDictionary` object that in normal circumstances will contain about 400-500 objects, and in some cases may contain 1500-2000.  The objects it contains are all `NSMutableArray` objects, each of which will normally contain 10-15 objects (a simple extender of `NSObject` with a few `NSString` and `NSDate` properties added) and may contain as many as 50.

By my seat-of-the-pants calculation (assuming 100 bytes per object?) this is about 5 MB on the low side and 80 MB on the high side, so I'm not sure this is a good idea.

On the iPhone, how big would you want a structure like this to be before you had to implement some form of caching?

Comment: do you need all these objects in memory? I try and keep in memory objects low out of habit, but don't optimise prematurely. when you run this on your iPhone are you getting memory warnings? try with itunes playing in the background. I would definitely look at running it in instruments with the allocations tool. also, if they are just collections of strings and dates, they could easily be persisted to Core Data, which would deal with a lot of the memory management stuff for you.

Comment: @MCannon: a user normally only needs to deal with 30-40 `NSMutableArray` objects at a time, so I will probably persist the rest (once I learn how to do that). I'm trying to get a general sense of what size of in-memory structures the iPhone can handle with relatively little problem. I come from a Windows Mobile background, and a WM device circa 2006 could handle a 5 MB structure with no problem, so I'm assuming that an iPhone can at least handle that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you'll potentially run out of memory at as low as 20MBs (on the iPhone 3G), you will want to rethink your design.  The 3G had 128MBs of RAM, the 3GS has 256MBs, and the iPhone 4 has 512MBs, but the amount available to your application is way less.  When I was working (and running into limits) on a 3G, I found that number to float around 20-25MBs.

The question is why do you need all the objects in memory at the same time?  You can store that data to disk and it might not slow your application down all that much.  Better to slow it down a little than to be constantly reaching the memory warning threshold, where you'll either need to trim that dictionary's size down or find your app crashing.

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely look at storing the objects into core data, as it will manage pulling in the required objects in time, and faulting the others until the data is accessed. it is very efficient and there are fetchResultControllers available to make integration easier.